# Plex Appliance for HP PC

Tags: server, plex

I've been struggling to set up a dedicated headless Plex server for a few days now. Learned a lot along the way but once again hit a brick wall.

Now my **question** is at this point; is the Plex appliance strictly for NUC's and Rpi's?
Or could I set this up on a different Intel based PC as well? Then at least I know whether to continue down this path or go back to start.

The [page](https://ubuntu.com/appliance/plex) states:

> **Try it out!**
>
> *Grab a spare board, PC or NUC. We also have instructions for virtual machine testing of appliances.*

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Comment: Setting up a headless Plex server can be pretty easy: 1) Install Ubuntu Server (w/screen&keyboard), 2) Give Ubuntu a static IP address so you can find it from elsewhere on your LAN, 3) Set up SSH access so you can disconnect the screen/keyboard, 4) Install Plex, 5) Open the server's Plex web page from your laptop/client and begin configuring it. How to do each step has been repeatedly documented. Perhaps you should open a new question about which step you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you have linked to, "*appliance*" refers to a specific combination of an Ubuntu Core base with a Plex Snap.

- The Plex *appliance* is NOT hardware-specific. It will run on any 64-bit Intel/AMD-based hardware that a normal Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Core will run on.
- *Appliances* will automatically update themselves when online. This is intended to protect your appliance from obsolescence or from being compromised.
- However, *appliances* are not designed to be expandable, and are usually locked-down. You may not be able to add new features or services or customizations to it.
- Generally, running an *appliance* on faster, more capable hardware might be squandering the capabilities of that hardware. For better hardware, consider instead using Ubuntu Server with the same Plex Snap -- same Plex experience, but the base system is expandable and customizable.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. So I’ll go back to a clean start, since I also want Transmission and Samba services running. 

My previous attempt was to have headless vnc, but I broke the gui along the way :)

Comment: Suggestion #1: Keep notes that enable you to properly uninstall or reinstall any application or backup that application's data. Folks think they will remember. They don't. Suggestion #2: Embrace Ubuntu Server's lack of GUI. The shell is powerful, flexible, and easy...with good notes. Use ssh for remote admin. Suggestion #3: LXD or Docker containers are great for experimenting without mucking up your base OS.